# Why does this not produce an error when referencing a string with an out of bounds index?

Tags: c, indexing

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeString(char text[], int beg, int remove)
{
    int index;

    for(index = beg; text[index + remove] != '\0'; index++)
        text[index] = text[index + remove];

    text[index] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char text [] = "the wrong son";
    removeString(text, 3, 40);
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

Comment: Why should it? Who told you it would?

Comment: Undefined behavior is not required to produce errors. It is, well, undefined.

Comment: You could rewrite the method as `strcpy(text+beg, text+beg+remove);`

Answer (score 2):

C does not have any bounds checking.  You can refer to anything you like and it's up to you to make sure it makes sense.

Depending on the platform and other factors, you can get garbage, memory exceptions or any other random crashes as your code corrupts memory and the stack.

Comment: The code works and produces the result I want. It does not return garbage values.

Comment: Probably the value at text+43 is a readable zero.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, is there a reason as to why it is a readable zero?

Comment: Could be anything.  There might be another global variable.  As a string constant, `text` could be bundled up with any other strings from error messages, library constants etc. who knows.  That's the nature of C.  Sometimes wrong will work until something apparently unrelated changes.  I'd not rely on it that's for sure!